# How to convert HashMap to json Array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to **convert [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to [json array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)** my code is as follow:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("first", "First Value");

map.put("second", "Second Value");
```

**I have tried this but it didn't work**. Any solution?

```
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(map));
```

Comment: So, you have a *Map*, but want an *Array*? Well, do that conversion first, *independent of JSON*, and then give the result (which is now a List/Array) to the appropriate JSON converter. The code posted won't work - and will result in a compiler error, which should be included in the post - because there is no `Arrays.asList(Map<K,V>)`, as that doesn't make sense as there is no universal conversion (although, perhaps you want a List of the Entries?). That is, this question/problem has nothing to do with JSON directly.

Comment: @pst: thanks but there is any solution on it? to create array with key=> value and convert it to json? in android activity

Comment: Arrays *don't have* "key=>value". Provide sample Map data and the expected JSON Array output.

Comment: Key value is only available with Map family in collection,try to convert Map into String and play with String.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this,

```
public JSONObject (Map copyFrom)
```

Creates a new JSONObject by copying all name/value mappings from the given map.

Parameters
copyFrom  a map whose keys are of type String and whose values are of supported types.

Throws
NullPointerException  if any of the map's keys are null.

Basic usage:

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(yourmap);
```

**get the json array from the JSONObject**

**Edit:**

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(obj.toString());
```

**Edit:**(If found Exception then You can change as mention in comment by  @krb686)

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray("["+obj.toString()+"]");
```

Comment: I have tried but didn't work. Could you please paste code here?

Comment: I have no idea by what logic that is supposed to work. I can only hope it's tested - showing input and what it produces (at each stage) would make this an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Pragnani Unfortunately this doesn't work.  Maybe it used to, but it doesn't anymore.  This throws:

`A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1`

At the line creating the JSONArray from the JSONObject

**Fix** You need to change to: `JSONArray array=new JSONArray("[" + obj.toString() + "]");`

Could you edit that? Thanks

Comment: In java 7, api 26 android, none of the solutions above produce a valid json array output. The map.toString() function produces braces, {}, not brackets, []

Answer (score 16):

Since androiad API Lvl 19, you can simply do `new JSONObject(new HashMap())`. But on older API lvls you get ugly result(simple apply toString to each non-primitive value).

I collected methods from JSONObject and JSONArray for simplify and beautifully result. You can use my solution class:

```java
package you.package.name;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonUtils
{
    public static JSONObject mapToJson(Map<?, ?> data)
    {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : data.entrySet())
        {
            /*
             * Deviate from the original by checking that keys are non-null and
             * of the proper type. (We still defer validating the values).
             */
            String key = (String) entry.getKey();
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
            }
            try
            {
                object.put(key, wrap(entry.getValue()));
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return object;
    }

    public static JSONArray collectionToJson(Collection data)
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        if (data != null)
        {
            for (Object aData : data)
            {
                jsonArray.put(wrap(aData));
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }

    public static JSONArray arrayToJson(Object data) throws JSONException
    {
        if (!data.getClass().isArray())
        {
            throw new JSONException("Not a primitive data: " + data.getClass());
        }
        final int length = Array.getLength(data);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            jsonArray.put(wrap(Array.get(data, i)));
        }

        return jsonArray;
    }

    private static Object wrap(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (o instanceof JSONArray || o instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            return o;
        }
        try
        {
            if (o instanceof Collection)
            {
                return collectionToJson((Collection) o);
            }
            else if (o.getClass().isArray())
            {
                return arrayToJson(o);
            }
            if (o instanceof Map)
            {
                return mapToJson((Map) o);
            }
            if (o instanceof Boolean ||
                    o instanceof Byte ||
                    o instanceof Character ||
                    o instanceof Double ||
                    o instanceof Float ||
                    o instanceof Integer ||
                    o instanceof Long ||
                    o instanceof Short ||
                    o instanceof String)
            {
                return o;
            }
            if (o.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("java."))
            {
                return o.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then if you apply mapToJson() method to your Map, you can get result like this:

```
{
  "int": 1,
  "Integer": 2,
  "String": "a",
  "int[]": [1,2,3],
  "Integer[]": [4, 5, 6],
  "String[]": ["a","b","c"],
  "Collection": [1,2,"a"],
  "Map": {
    "b": "B",
    "c": "C",
    "a": "A"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  I wish I could give this +10!  I'll have to look at the source code for API 19 to see if this is what they're doing.  Thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem with undecodable string being sent looking like:

{key=value, key2=value2}

Answer (score 3):

A map consists of key / value pairs, i.e. two objects for each entry, whereas a list only has a single object for each entry. What you can do is to extract all [Map.Entry<K,V>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) and then put them in the array:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String> entries = map.entrySet();
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(entries);
```

Alternatively, sometimes it is useful to extract the keys *or* the values to a collection:

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(keys);
```

or

```
List<String> values = map.values();
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(values);
```

Note: If you choose to use the *keys* as entries, the order is not guaranteed (the `keySet()` method returns a `Set`). That is because the `Map` interface does not specify any order (unless the `Map` happens to be a `SortedMap`).

Answer (score 2):

This is the Simplest Method.

Just use

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(hashmapobject.toString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`JSONArray jarray = JSONArray.fromObject(map );`

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210273/how-to-create-a-complex-json-using-hashmap-in-android

Comment: These classes are available in **JSON-Lib** library. You can find this library here: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Forhad: Thanks, But my hash created dynamically in my code so its not suitable for me is any other option to create array with key=>value and convert in json in android activity?