# How to get Result of LinkedHashMap within Inverted commas

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app in which I have to send `LinkedHashMap` results by API but the problem what I am getting is format of result is different. How can I put keys and values both in inverted commas?

I'm getting result like this:

```
list: {0=816444014066, 1=747083010945, 2=816444010969}
```

And I want result like this:

```
list: {"0" : "816444014066","1" : "747083010945","2" : "816444010969"}
```

How to change the format of result?

Comment: How can you send API response as LinkedHashMap? I think API response is either JSON or XML.

Comment: http://demo?store_id=8&sku=&upc_array=[{"0":"816444014073"}]

Comment: its POST request of JSON

Answer (score 2):

Use My Answer. It worked for me.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
// Instantiate a new Gson instance.
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Convert the ordered map into an ordered string.
        String json = gson.toJson(data, LinkedHashMap.class);

        // Print ordered string.
        Log.e("list", ""+json); //  {"0" : "816444014066","1" : "747083010945","2" : "816444010969"}
```

Comment: this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

To get the quotes you need to make your keys and values `String` in your `LinkedHashMap`

**Edit:**

maybe what you need is already provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402321/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-array-in-android) answer

Comment: both are already String @Peppermint

Comment: how do you convert your linkedhashmap to string, just by using `toString()``method?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can put quotes to String with :

```
String value = " \"1\" ";
```

You could do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> linkedmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
linkedHashMap.put(setQuotes("1"), setQuotes("5445454"));

public static String setQuotes(String value){
     String result = "";
     if(!value.isEmpty()){
          result = "\"" + value + "\"";   
     }
     return result;
}
```

If you print it in the console, it returns:

```
{"1"="5445454"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that possibility is to create your own `Map` class that extends `LinkedHashMap` and to create and implement in it method with behavior similar to behavior of `toString()` method. This link might help you to get started with implementation of that method:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.toString%28%29